# For a "space" within two printed strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = "hacker"
h = [x for x in range(0,len(s))]
m = list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0 ,h))
for i in m:
    print(s[i],end = '')
for i in m:         
    print(s[i],end = '')
```

When I run this code it shows `hcehce` in output but I want the output to be `hce hce`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `print(" ", end='')` after the first for loop. This will add the space between each time you use your for loop. Your code should look like this.

```
s = "hacker"
h = [x for x in range(0,len(s))]
m = list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0 ,h))
for i in m:
    print(s[i],end = '')

print(" ", end='')

for i in m:         
    print(s[i],end = '')
```